# Torque on a quarter-wave plate… Where is the force? Where is the moment arm?

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, torque, polarization

If you shine circularly polarized light (carrying angular momentum) through a quarter-wave plate, the light will emerge as linearly polarized light (carrying no angular momentum) from the other side. In order for momentum to be conserved, the plate must experience a torque. How does this work? Where is the force acting?